# I need to fix the results of a postgres query

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to filter on an array clause with just one row per "date (t1.starttime)". The current return creates a row for each item in the array. I have tried selecting distinct on t1.starttime but that is only returning results from the first t3.store.

```
SELECT
t2.name,
date (t1.starttime),
Count(t1.starttime) as "# Plays",
Count(distinct(t1.playerid)) as "# Stores"

FROM
public.billing t1 JOIN public.medias t2 on t1.mediaitemid = t2.id 
JOIN public.players t3 on t1.playerid = t3.id 

WHERE
t3.store in  ('0038','3285') and
t2.name LIKE any (array['COMM_7032%']) and
t1.starttime >= date('2017-04-26') and 
t1.starttime < date('2017-05-01') and
t1.channelname = 'myNetwork'

GROUP BY
date (t1.starttime),
t2.name,
t1.playerid

ORDER BY
date (t1.starttime)
```

Returned Data...

```
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-27";20;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-27";20;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-28";34;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-28";34;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-29";35;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-29";35;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-30";21;1
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-30";22;1
```

Trying to combine the dates so it reads like this...

```
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-27";40;2 
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-28";68;2 
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-29";70;2 
"COMM_7032";"2017-04-30";43;2
```

Comment: Did you try just removing `t1.playerid` from the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: I have, but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try this one if it fits:

```
SELECT
array_agg(t2.name),
array_agg(t1.playerid),
date (t1.starttime),
Count(t1.starttime) as "# Plays",
Count(distinct(t1.playerid)) as "# Stores"

FROM
public.billing t1 JOIN public.medias t2 on t1.mediaitemid = t2.id 
JOIN public.players t3 on t1.playerid = t3.id 

WHERE
t3.store in  ('0038','3285') and
t2.name LIKE any (array['COMM_7032%']) and
t1.starttime >= date('2017-04-26') and 
t1.starttime < date('2017-05-01') and
t1.channelname = 'myNetwork'

GROUP BY
date (t1.starttime)

ORDER BY
date (t1.starttime)
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm.